# Why does -a in "#!/bin/sh -a" affect sed and "set -a" doesn't?

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, options

If I run the following .sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh -a
echo "a" | sed -e 's/[\d001-\d008]//g'
```

The result is an error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 18: Invalid range end

But if I run the following .sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -a
echo "a" | sed -e 's/[\d001-\d008]//g'
```

It runs without error.
Isn't the second code supposed to be equivalent of the first one? Why the error in the first one?

Comment: Not all `sh` are the same. Nor all sed are equivalent. Which `sh` are you using? In which OS? and Which sed (maybe? `sed --version` if it doesn't fail)?

Comment: I am running inside a docker container based on centos:7.

Comment: setting `LC_COLLATE=C` (or `POSIX`) for the call to `sed` works around the issue

Comment: Sed version 4.2.2, uname -a outputs: Linux e04417cb9083 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 12 15:04:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Created a t.sh file with that content. chmod +x t.sh. Then running with ./t.sh

Comment: You are probably not using bash, and `set -a` and invoking the shell with `-a` may do different things.

Comment: @wurtel that script uses sh on the shebang... so I guess it is running on sh not bash. But still... why the error?

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, that's why I am not understand the error. I was using that in a bigger script that uses variables, that's why i am setting it. But caught this error when configuring on shebang.

Comment: Please [download and execute this script](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/whatshell/) to **try** to identify your shell. It seems that Centos use dash, but dash does not have such error.

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes, LC_COLLATE=C works around it. Do you know why the error when LC_COLLATE is "en_US.UTF-8"? And why it only happens when -a is on the shebang not when using set?

Comment: I do not; I only had enough time to get to that point.

Comment: @Isaac bash 4.2.46(1)-release

Comment: Bash version 4.2 acts the same in both conditions. The only option is the the Centos kernel process shebang options in a different way (which I do not believe it is). Anyone with Centos available to test?

Comment: @ilkkachu and easier `Invalid range` is `[A-a]` or even a safer bet `[~--]`.

Comment: @Isaac, or `[b-a]`. Yeah, that makes more sense for the error message.

Comment: @Isaac
    0000000 60 5e 7e 3c 3d 3e 7c 20 5f 2d 2c 3b 3a 21 3f 2f
    0000020 2e 27 22 28 29 5b 5d 7b 7d 40 24 2a 5c 26 23 25
    0000040 2b 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10
    0000060 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 30
    0000100 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 61 41 62 42 63 43 64
    0000120 44 65 45 66 46 67 47 68 48 69 49 6a 4a 6b 4b 6c
    0000140 4c 6d 4d 6e 4e 6f 4f 70 50 71 51 72 52 73 53 74
    0000160 54 75 55 76 56 77 57 78 58 79 59 7a 5a
    0000175

Comment: That is the collation order, the sequence that sed use (probably) to know which characters are before or after another one. Your result is identical to my result (with a en_US.utf8 locale). I can not understand why you get a problem. And I can not reproduce …!

Comment: @Isaac Are you using CentOS? According to ikkachu above it does not reproduce on Debian. May be some kind of bug specific to CentOS.

Comment: No, as [I have said in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462333/why-does-a-in-bin-sh-a-affects-sed-and-set-a-doesnt?noredirect=1#comment841232_462333) I have no Centos available to try. You will have to wait for someone that does.  :(

Comment: @Isaac if you have docker you can start a temporary centos shell with `docker run -it --rm centos:7`. You can also run that online at [katacoda](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/docker/playground), but there I could not paste text.

Comment: One difference I found: the first script invokes sed (and presumably any other utility) with `POSIXLY_CORRECT=y` in the environment, the second does not have `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in the environment. The shell I invoke both scripts from does not have `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in its environment.

Comment: Only using the docker I commented above will not reproduce because the default locale of the docker container is POSIX. But doing `export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"` before executing the script reproduces it.

Comment: Ah, `echo "a" | POSIXLY_CORRECT=y sed -e 's/[\d001-\d008]//g'`  reproduce your problem

Comment: Looks like what's happening is that if bash is invoked as `...../sh`, it will set the variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT` to `y`, and **if the -a flag is in effect at the time, i.e. is passed as an option**, it'll be automatically exported. `POSIXLY_CORRECT=y` makes awk complain about `[\d001-\d008]`.

Comment: @Isaac I put the `env` command into the scripts and diffed the outputs. I also used `strace` to see if `awk` was invoked differently.

Comment: That match the symptom of the OP, but the OP have not said that POSIXLY_CORRECT was set in any of the scripts. @MarkPlotnick

Comment: @Rodrigo Please add a line to `echo "$POSIXLY_CORRECT"` in each of the scripts and run them again.

Comment: @Isaac `echo "$POSIXLY_CORRECT"` inside the script prints `y` for both cases.

Comment: Please change `awk` to `sed` in my previous comments - sorry.

Comment: Then it may be that the value is exported in one script but not in the other. Please add `env | grep POSIXLY_CORRECT` just after the shebang. It is probable that the -a triggers an automatic export to environment when that value is set on shell start, but not on a latter `set -a` (as the variable is not set again, if it is set or changed, it will be auto-exported).

Comment: In the sh commandline.... `echo "$POSIXLY_CORRECT"` outputs `y`. `echo "a" | POSIXLY_CORRECT=y sed -e 's/[\d001-\d008]//g'` does error. `echo "a" | sed -e 's/[\d001-\d008]//g'` works correctly. If I `export LC_COLLATE=C` there is no error in both cases. (got here thanks to above informations from @Isaac, @MarkPlotnick and @JeffSchaller... but still why this happens?)

Comment: @Rodrigo Exactly what I reported 1 hour ago: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462333/why-does-a-in-bin-sh-a-affects-sed-and-set-a-doesnt?noredirect=1#comment841281_462333

Comment: Confirming that the above fails for me exactly as the OP has shown on CentOS 7.x - GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) & CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When bash is called with the name `sh`, it [does this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c?h=bash-4.2#n1589):

```
if (shell_name[0] == 's' && shell_name[1] == 'h' && shell_name[2] == '\0')
    act_like_sh++;
```

and then later [sets the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` shell variable to `y`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c?h=bash-4.2#n654):

```
if (act_like_sh)
  {
    bind_variable ("POSIXLY_CORRECT", "y", 0);
    sv_strict_posix ("POSIXLY_CORRECT");
  }
```

`bind_variable` calls `bind_variable_internal`, which, if the shell attribute `a` is on at the time (which it would be if you invoked the shell with `-a`), [marks the shell variable as *exported*](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c?h=bash-4.2#n2262).

So in your first script:

```
#!/bin/sh -a
echo "a" | sed -e 's/[\d001-\d008]//g'
```

`sed` is invoked with `POSIXLY_CORRECT=y` in its environment, which will make it complain about `[\d001-\d008]`. (Same thing happens if sed is given the `--posix` option.)

In GNU sed, `\dNNN` is an escape code for the character whose numerical value in base-10 is *NNN*, but in POSIX mode, this is disabled inside a bracket expression, so `[\d001-\d008]`, means literally the characters `\`, `d`, etc., with the range being from `1` to `\`. In order of character codes, `1` comes before `\` (and the range includes all digits except zero, plus all uppercase letters, plus some special characters). In the `en_US.UTF-8` locale which you were using, `\` sorts before `1`, however, so the range is invalid.

In your second script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -a
echo "a" | sed -e 's/[\d001-\d008]//g'
```

even though `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set in the shell, it isn't exported, so sed is invoked without `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in the environment, and sed runs with GNU extensions.

If you add `export POSIXLY_CORRECT` near the top of your second script, you'll also see sed complain.

Comment: To me, that's a bug.

Comment: holy shell horror, Batman! That's an interesting quirk (and a bit of a change to see an issue that comes from `/bin/sh` actually _being_ Bash). The same happens if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment before the `sh` Bash starts: it will also pass it on as `POSIXLY_CORRECT=y`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas its a little off - but it makes sense - ive seen the behavior before in my scripts - the `set -a` only effects variables declared after it - `sh -a` is understandably different because `-a` is being utilized at time of shell invocation - so it would follow that all variables in the environment and script would be exported

Comment: @StevenPenny, but `POSIXLY_CORRECT` _isn't_ in the environment when the shell starts, and the script doesn't set it. The shell does. It creates an environment variable out of nowhere, which is extra bad since it does that in a mode where it's supposed to be, and tries to be standard-compliant.

Comment: FWIW, Bash also doesn't seem to document that it would set `POSIXLY_CORRECT` on its own. There's no mention of it in the [list of effects of POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html) and the [variable description](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-POSIXLY_005fCORRECT) only says that setting it changes the shell to POSIX mode, not the other way around.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, care to make a bug report about it?

Comment: @ilkkachu. Done. I think the POSIX spec should also be updated to clarify what variables are affected by `allexport`.

Comment: @ilkkachu, [POSIX issue now raised as well](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg02754.html).